# Error: Couldnt connect with Foursquare webservice

Tags: foursquare

I tried to connect to the Foursquare webservice to parse look for some locations, but my program couldn't connect with Foursquare webservice. Here is my code:

public class GetLocation
{

```
public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException
{

    //Set up for output locations in a .txt file
    String fileNameOut = "locations.txt" ; 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileNameOut );
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
    String client_id = "Y2LZCJTR4LJBXZOXAB3F22VOLAV3GXRS5TSXRXXXXXXXXXXX";
    String client_secret = "PJY2QM4CLZITAUMGOQCM2QYTOKATTCH3VXXXXXXXXXXX";

    double latitude = 33.823712;
    double longtitude = -117.958931;
    String restaurantName = "Cafe Casse Croute";
    String V = "20121205";

            String API_URL = "http://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=";
        String queryStatement = latitude+","+longtitude+"&match="+restaurantName;

           try {
                 String url = (API_URL+queryStatement+"&client_id="+client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret + "&v="+V);


           URL url = new URL(sURL);

           URLConnection httpc = url.openConnection();
       //HttpURLConnection httpc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();    
           httpc.setDoInput(true);
           httpc.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpc.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine = "";
        String content="";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
             content=content+inputLine;

        }
        in.close();

        return content;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

I also try to use URLConnection httpc = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
but it does not connect to the FoureSquare Service.

Is there other way to connect to the FoureSquare Service ?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to publicize your client secret. I recommend you change your client secret, and update the question to not show this to others.

Comment: Thank you very much Pfhayes. Do you have any idea about connection to the foursquare service ?